# Django multiple foreign keys to reference same table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, django, database, database-design, database-schema

I am putting together a Django site using MySQL. Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out how to put my schema together.

I have a Users table, a Tasks table, and a Session table.

Each user can have 3 active tasks at a time. Each user can update (set to complete, fail, or keep open) those three tasks per work session. If a user completes the task (i.e. has less than three open tasks), the next time they create a session they will be given the opportunity to create a new task. This last part is easy enough to code, it's the logic underpinning the table schema that is giving me trouble.

My problem is that I don't know how to model this properly. At first I thought of including 3 separate columns in the Session table with foreign keys pointing to the Task table. However, from what I'm reading, it doesn't look like I can add 3 foreign keys all referencing different instances of the same table. Alternatively, I thought about creating a many-to-many table between session and task. However, would I then have to create three table entries per open session? That seems like it could get out of hand very quickly, and also just seems sloppy to me.

I am honestly just at a complete loss as to how to model this. I would really appreciate any help or input.

Thank you

Comment: "*It doesn't look like I can add 3 foreign keys all referencing different instances of the same table*". Sure you can. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm going to be honest here: I hadn't. I let myself get lost in a sea of documentation and all-but convinced myself that this solution wouldn't work. Stupid of me... Thanks for the reality check!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    task_1 = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    task_2 = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    task_3 = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

Comment: A quick update. I tried this method, but it would not work until I set a "related_name" field for each of the task foreign keys like so. "task_1 = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="task_one")"

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** When referencing the same model(table) multiple times from another model(table) in Django, you must add **related_name** argument.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    task_1 = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='task_one')
    task_2 = models.ForeignKey(Task related_name='task_two')
    task_3 = models.ForeignKey(Task related_name='task_three')
```